# Drool rule to specify only to fire for Parent not for its child

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-planner

I have two java object(Let say Parent and Child..child extends parent).But I need to specify rule fire only for parent not for its child.

Ex:

```
when 
    $raw : Parent()
then
    System.out.println(" Parent")
end
----
when 
    $raw : Child()
then
    System.out.println(" Child")
end
```

If I try to inject child object as a fact, it fire for both. I am not able to use not Child() bz I have  lots of child.Thanks

Best regards,
Nipuna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me say that the necessity of distinguishing a Parent object from any of its subclasses is very likely a design flaw. If you need rules that apply only to the Parent and not to any of its subclasses it is an indication that Parent is going to be processed *in parallel* to its children. To resolve, don't insert Parent objects but create another subclass

```
class ChildWithoutAdditionalProperties extends Parent {
}
```

and insert objects of this class.

Second, `not Child()` does not match objects of any other class besides `Child` as your remark "I am not able to use not Child()" seems to indicate: It will match for the absence of any Child fact.

To test that an object is of a certain class, you can compare the class of that object:

```
rule "parent"
when
    $e: Parent( $e.getClass == Parent.class )
then
    System.out.println( "found Parent" );
end
```

Comment: This helps me a lot. Thanks.Appreciated.